# Banner Stats and Google Analytics Using PHP

Tags: php, seo, google-analytics

I have created an affiliate banner script which is, from what I have seen, is quite unique.  I am limited by an NDA so please understand if I cannot provide actual pages or the domain name.

The affiliate has an option of eight different banners of various sizes.  The code provided to the affiliate is all in CSS layout - simple divs and paragraphs - with a single anchor containing no onclick call and the src contains no query string.  The affiliate code also provides a call to a javascript file on my client's server.  The anchor text (keywords) varies based on affiliate_id.  The src of the script call defines the banner type and the affiliate id in the format: http://www.somedomain.com/banner_dir/affiliate_id/banner_id/.  Using .htaccess, the index page in the banner_dir has the extension .js but interprets PHP code.  The index.js parses out the directory structure to extract the affiliate_id and banner_id.

If you can follow this so far, the index.js using PHP creates a session on the client's server which assigns the session vars affiliate_id, banner_id, keywords and referring domain.  Statistics are saved to a couple of stats tables.  The script drops out of PHP, then writes to the affiliates page the style sheet for the banner using document.write().

In summary, what I have done here is to create a cross-domain cookie using every trick in I could come up with with the intent of creating content on a remote server which will maximize SEO for my client, with minimal negative SEO.  And, yeah, it works.

When the banner is clicked, there is interpretive code on the client's server to record a click of the banner pulling the values from the session.

So far  have met every requirement by the client except one.  He wants to pass the statistcs to his Google Analytics account.  I need to be able to generate stats for the display and click of the banner based on affiliate_id, banner type, and keywords.  The client needs to be able to evaluate the efficacy of keywords and banners and performance of affiliates.  Ideally, we would be able to track the customer from a banner view to the successful sale.

In the past, I have used tracking code using a link structure similar to that I am using for the JS call to client's server, though, in this situation, I think a campaign would be more effective in generating the stats.

I can pass the initial GA code when the index.js script exits but I have some problems with the click thru event.  I want to avoid using a click event when the anchor in the banner is clicked, keeping the code as clean as possible.  Ideally, I would like to make a background call when my client's site is accessed, since the code which interprets the session data involves a PHP redirect and nothing can be written prior to the redirect without error.

Any questions, comments or suggestions?

I haven't quite gotten the hang of the interface of this venue, so please excuse post lower in this thread.  Anyway, this is the code I am using.  The data is being posted from the click and display scripts via cURL and I know it is being called.  However, the data is not getting to Google Analytics.

```
<? 
$f = $_POST['banner']; 
$a = $_POST['affiliate_id']; 
$r = urlencode ($_POST['referrer']); 
$k = $_POST['keywords']; 
// $_POST['c'] = the click event 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
     <title>GA Display script</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
function loadtracking() { 
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXXX-X']); 
_gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'banners']);    // name 
_gaq.push(['_setCampMediumKey', '<?=$f?>']);  // image 
_gaq.push(['_setCampSourceKey', '<?=$a?>']);  // source 
_gaq.push(['_setCampTermKey', '<?=$k?>']);   // term/keyword 
_gaq.push(['_setReferrerOverride(<?=$r?>)']); 
_gaq.push(['_setCampContentKey', '<?=$k?>']);  // content 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 
<?if ($_POST['c'] == 1){?>  
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banners', 'Click', 'Banner Click-thru']); 
<?}else{?>  
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'banners', 'Display', 'Banner Display']); 
<?}?> 
(function() { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
    ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ga.async = true; 
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
  })(); 
} 
loadtracking(); 
</script>  
</head> 
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for ajax. You state that you don't want to be dependant on a click event so instead you want to act when your client site is accessed. If you create a remote javascript file and add a reference to it on the client's site, would this not serve your intentions?

Let me know if I understood you correctly or if that helps in any way.

Comment: Just a followup here. I have everything working except for the GA tracking code.  It is another hybrid PHP/JS script which is called from both the banner display and click scripts.  I am using cURL to post the variables (which are assigned in the first few lines of the following code for clarity).  I know the script is being called successfully as I had it email me with the post array in the development process.  However, the data is not being received by GA.  It is likely something silly I am not seeing.